# How do I change a scripts variable from a different object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I have a shrink button and a ball. When I click the shrink button the ball should play the shrinking animation.

I am trying to change the "shrink" variable so the animation will know to play.

Shrink button code:

```
   private ShrinkBall referenceScript;

   void Start()
   {
       referenceScript = ball.GetComponent<ShrinkBall>();
   }

   void OnMouseDown()
   {
       if (referenceScript.shrink == true)
       {
           referenceScript.shrink = true;
       } else
       {
           referenceScript.shrink = false;
       }
}
```

Ball script:

```
public bool shrink = false;
    private Animator shrinkAnim;

    void Start()
    {
        shrinkAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (shrink == false)
        {
            shrinkAnim.SetBool("shrink", false);
        } else
        {
            shrinkAnim.SetBool("shrink", true);
        }
    }
```

When I click the shrink button, the "shrink" variable remains false. I know it's accessing it because it initially told me it was out of scope, so I made it a public variable.

So the animation never plays because shrink doesn't change. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at your code - you do not appear to change the shrink variable - if is true then you set it to true otherwise you set it to false - so nothing gets changed. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Are both of these scripts monobehaviors? Are you certain that "ball" is set to the correct GameObject that you expect in `referenceScript = ball.GetComponent<ShrinkBall>();`

Does the button script extend iPointerDownEvents interface? Those are important for the above even to be triggered. 

Is the object in "Ignore Raycast" layers? That would prevent triggering. 

Without seeing the full scripts, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Also, use properties for this:
`public bool shrink {get;set}`

Comment: why are you reassigning `referenceScript.shrink` with `true` if it's already `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never changing the `shrink` value but make it keep the same value it already has...

You probably rather wanted to do

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    referenceScript.shrink = !referenceScript.shrink;
}
```

---

Then you shouldn't use `SetBool` all the time in `Update` but rather only once you change it.

You could e.g. use a method like

```
public void ToggleShrink()
{
    shrink = !shrink;

    shrinkAnim.SetBool("shrink", shrink);
}
```

Then you could simply call it from the first script like

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    referenceScript.ToggleShrink();
}
```